# Importing files from other folders which have their own imports not working

Tags: python, directory

I have a file abc.py which imports another file xyz.py from the same folder location as abc.py. This works

Now when I try and import abc.py from an external folder it gives me no module found error on xyz?

what can i do?

What i am getting is
import stable.npi_component
File "/app/src/controllers/tests/../stable/abc.py", line 6, in 
import xyz as npc #base module that contains mapping and npi_context class
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module using a relative import, the search for the module will be relative to the current module. So, when you import xyz from abc.py, Python will search for xyz.py in the same directory as abc.py.

However, when you try to import abc.py from an external folder, Python will search for xyz.py in the same directory as the external folder, not in the same directory as abc.py.

To fix this, you can add the path to the directory containing xyz.py to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. You can do this by adding the following code at the beginning of your script:

```
import sys
import os

# Add the path to the directory containing xyz.py to the PYTHONPATH
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(dir_path, 'path_to_xyz_directory'))
```

Replace 'path_to_xyz_directory' with the actual path to the directory containing xyz.py.

Alternatively, you can use absolute imports in your code. Instead of import xyz, use import package.xyz, where package is the name of the package containing xyz.py. You can then add the path to the package directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.